# Ошибка при использовании JSON_ARRAYAGG с выражением CASE: ORA-40590: invalid format

Tags: sql, json, oracle

Использую Oracle 18c (воспроизводится и в 19c) и хотел бы применить стандартное SQL выражение  `CASE` в агрегатной функции `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`, чтобы исключить значения из агрегации.

Однако это приводит к ошибке ([на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=286f5a541a3733ed0dcf61cc8905b6db)):

```sql
select json_arrayagg (
    case when t.a < 2 then json_object (key 'a' value t.a) end) 
from (
    select 1 a from dual union all
    select 2 a from dual
) t
```

> ORA-40590: invalid format

Что вызывает эту ошибку? Это новый баг в Oracle?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Oracle bug when using JSON_ARRAYAGG with CASE expression to emulate standard SQL FILTER](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68177452) от участника [@Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/68177452

Answer (score 2):

Это действительно баг, [который был исправлен в 19.10](https://twitter.com/connor_mc_d/status/1409844145850503174)
*Прим.ред.:* текущий долгосрочный релиз 19.03.

Надо добавить явно условия `ELSE`, это решит проблему:

```sql
select json_arrayagg (
    case when t.a < 2 then json_object (key 'a' value t.a) 
    else null end)
----^^^^^^^^^     
from (
    select 1 a from dual union all
    select 2 a from dual
) t
```

Даст ожидаемый результат ([на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0804a01906a5a70e437f408d1a09211b)):

```
[{"a":1}]
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68177453) от участника [@Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder)</sub>